# Running TensorBoard on summaries on S3 server

Tags: amazon-s3, tensorflow, boto3, tensorboard

I want to use TensorBoard to visualize results stored on an S3 server, without downloading them to my machine. Ideally, this would work:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir s3://mybucket/summary
```

Assuming the `tfevents` files are stored under `summary`. However this does not work and returns `UnimplementedError: File system scheme s3 not implemented`.

Is there some workaround to enable TensorBoard to access the data on the server?

Comment: I don't know if its possible to read from S3. However, it's possible to use AWS' EFS to write and read Tensorboard summaries (mount it into your GPU and Tensorboard instance). I have this setup and it works quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S3 File system plugin for tensorflow was released in Version 1.4 in early October. You'll need to make sure your tensorflow-tensorboard version is at least `pip install tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0-rc1`

Then you can start the server:

`tensorboard --logdir=s3://root-bucket/jobs/4/train`